# How to resolve a 415 response when sending a Multipart file to a Spring Boot backend with React frontend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, jsx

I am using a React frontend with Spring Boot backend and axios. I am trying to send an image as a `Multipart` file using axios. Here is my function for sending the file in my React component:

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

    function handleSubmit(){
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/image/',
            selectedImage)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200){
                    console.log(response.data)
                    // window.location.href = "/user-dash"
                } else
                    console.log("nope")
                return Promise.reject("it broke")
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Here is the `.jsx` portion that is gathering the image data

```
<div>
            <h1>Upload and Display Image</h1>

            {selectedImage && (
                <div>
                    <img
                        alt="profile pic"
                        width={"250px"}
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Save</button>
                    <button onClick={() => setSelectedImage(null)}>Remove</button>
                </div>
            )}
            <input
                type="file"
                name="myImage"
                onChange={(event) => {
                    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
                    setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
                }}
            />
        </div>
```

The `console.log` outputs the `File` as I expect. Then the following controller gets it:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam(value = "myImage") MultipartFile file){
        String response = imageDataService.uploadImage(file);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(response);
    }
```

It is then sent to the `ImageDataService` which looks like this (Please note, I'm using Lombok):

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ImageDataService {

    private ImageDataRepository imageDataRepository;

    public String uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            imageDataRepository.save(ImageData.builder()
                    .name(file.getOriginalFilename())
                    .type(file.getContentType())
                    .imageData(ImageUtil.compressImage(file.getBytes())).build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return "Image uploaded successfully: " +
                file.getOriginalFilename();

    }

    @Transactional
    public ImageData getInfoByImageByName(String name) {
        Optional<ImageData> dbImage = imageDataRepository.findByName(name);

        return ImageData.builder()
                .name(dbImage.get().getName())
                .type(dbImage.get().getType())
                .imageData(ImageUtil.decompressImage(dbImage.get().getImageData())).build();

    }

    @Transactional
    public byte[] getImage(String name) {
        Optional<ImageData> dbImage = imageDataRepository.findByName(name);
        byte[] image = ImageUtil.decompressImage(dbImage.get().getImageData());
        return image;
    }


}
```

Finally, the `ImageDataRepository` gets it and is supposed to save an `ImageData` object in a table. first, the repository:

```
public interface ImageDataRepository extends JpaRepository<ImageData, Long> {
    Optional<ImageData> findByName(String name);
}
```

and here is the `ImageData` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageData")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ImageData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "imagedata", length = 1000)
    private byte[] imageData;
}
```

I have checked the database and there is no new line in the `image_data` table. I do not get a stacktrace in the server but I get a 415 response code. This would suggest to me that the `Content-Type` is not being set properly but when I specify the `Content-type: "multipart/form-data"` I get an error saying that "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found". When searching for a resolution to that issue, I found a solution that said to remove the content-type and that the boundary would be generated automagically. That no longer generated the boundary issue but it did create the 415 issue. Next, I tried adding a boundary to the `Content-Type` header like so:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/image/',
            selectedImage,{
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu"
            }
            })
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200){
                    console.log(response.data)
                    // window.location.href = "/user-dash"
                } else
                    console.log("nope")
                return Promise.reject("it broke")
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This also did not produce a stacktrace on the server but I did get a 400 error in the console and no data was saved to the `image_data` table.

I'm not sure where to go from here as all the solutions I've been able to find, are now creating a loop of errors. One solution leads to another problem who's solution eventually leads back to the original problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated and I would of course be happy to provide any info I may have left out. Thanks!

Comment: If I had this problem, I'd want to make sure my server-side method worked all by itself.  I'd use the simplest client possible, such as command line tools `curl` or .  I'd try uploading the simplest possible thing first, such as a text file.  Once that worked, I'd try an image.  Image might require the server method to declare that it accepts binary data.

Comment: When I google for "spring boot upload", I see a bunch of examples/tutorials.  Did you start with one of those?  It's good to start with a simple working example, then add more features to it, one small step at a time, to quickly catch a bug as soon as it's created.  So, in your case, I'd eliminate trying to save to the DB until after I verified, I could upload a text or image file and save them as files on the server.

Comment: @devdanke I also saw several tutorials and guides on how to do this. Unfortunately, the majority of them are outdated and use deprecated code in a lot of their examples. I've been updating the code they use as I go along but I have apparently missed a step. Just hoping someone here can catch it. Also, I tried using Postman but I'm so unfamiliar with it that I can't figure out if errors i get are my code or the lack of setting Postman up properly. I spent three days troubleshooting my last big issue only to find out that it was Postman not being set up right. Stopped using it after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After far too much searching, I finally found a solution. My `ImageDataController` was looking for a key called `myImage` as a `RequestParam`. Instead, I was giving it the file with no name. My controller couldn't find the key it was told to look for so it did nothing.

In order to fix it, I changed my `handleSubmit` function in the `.jsx` file to this:

```
function handleSubmit(){

        const upload = {
            "myImage": selectedImage //this creates the key that my controller was looking for and sets the value as the image
        }
        console.log(selectedImage.name)

        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/image/',
            upload,{
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu"
            }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.status)
                if(response.status === 200){
                    console.log(response.data)
                    // window.location.href = "/user-dash"
                } else
                    console.log("nope")
                return Promise.reject("it broke")
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Note the creation of the `upload` variable and setting the `selectedImage` as the value of it. Hopefully this helps someone else